# How many routers can the Powerbank power and how long?

Tags: power, router, powerbanks

I have a power bank,
Capacity: 27000mAh/99.9WH
Input: 19V/1.6A
AC output: 220V/50Hz 100w Max

Router (MR600)
Input: 100-240v 50/60hz 0.6A
output 12v 1.5A

Comment: That router requires 12V @ 1.5A (18 watts), you are losing a lot by converting the battery bank to AC, then from AC back to DC for the router. By the way "how many for how long" are mutually exclusive, you can power 1 router for a long time, or 100 routers for a very short time, there is no answer here for two variables.

Comment: Assuming 0.3A at 220v, that's 66 watts. So an hour and a half for 1 router. Not accounting for variable draw or the power banks voltage drop.

Comment: To find how long battery can power up a router is 27000mAh divide 1.5A ? or 99.9Wh divide by router's watt which is 66watts?

Answer (score 0):

Considering an 80% efficient conversion to power up the routers, we have
$$ \frac{100 Wh \cdot0.80}{ 12 V \cdot1.5A /router} = \frac{80 Wh}{ 18W /router} = 6.66 h \cdot router.$$
Meaning for 1 router, 6.66h, for 2 routers 3.33, and so on.

Comment: I considered 80% efficiency, but if the router power brick has an input 100-240v 50/60hz **consuming 0.6A** for an output of 12v 1.5A, you will have less than 30% efficiency, that is not a good choice, it is better to use 12V batteries or something else.

Comment: You can rarely trust the input current statement for wall PSU's. I believe it to be maximum inrush current they try to state. 30% efficiency power conversion is appalling, almost to an illegal degree.